# Spherical environment map blurry

Tags: three.js, aframe

I took an `equirectangular envMap` from the [three.js docs sample](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=env#webgl_materials_envmaps) where it appears sharp on a sphere.

If I load the same material into my [aframe](/questions/tagged/aframe) scene with the following params

```js
material="spherical-env-map: /assets/models/1/envtest.jpeg; roughness: 0; metalness: 1"
```

it appears blurry like this

[image: blurry env map]

What am I doing wrong?

Reproducible example via glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sepia-forest-keyboard

What I have noticed when setting up the glitch:

- Using `Aframe 1.0.3` it is blurry
- Using `Aframe 1.2.0` it remains black no matter what I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you are using a PBR material in your code since the default material of A-Frame is [MeshStandardMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=meshs#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial). Meaning a material that tries to render physically correct. The official `three.js` example uses [MeshLambertMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=meshs#api/en/materials/MeshLambertMaterial) which is no PBR material. Both type of materials implement environment maps differently.

When using a PBR material, it's recommended to use a HDR environment map which is also pre-processed with `PMREMGenerator` like in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf

Comment: Thanks! I fail to see how I can implement the `PREMGenerator` within [tag:aframe]. I do have a `.hdr` file available for the environment as well, however it is not loaded at all (no error msg either) when using `spherical-env-map`. Unfortunately there is little to no documentation about this, I appreciate any sort of hint!

Comment: You can try [registering a shader](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/material.html#registershader) (applying the MeshLambertMaterial), or just use the `entity.getObject3D("mesh").material` reference to apply any "raw" THREE material (like in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-67694530?path=index.html%3A13%3A90).